# Why is the value of $A$, in the expression for Boltzmann's distribution of speeds, not directly calculated?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetic-theory-of-gases

I've read the proof for the expression for Boltzmann's distribution of speeds on this [site](https://www.vedantu.com/physics/maxwell-boltzmann-distribution-derivation). There, $f(v)$ is first factorized into $f(v_x)$, $f(v_y)$ and $f(v_z)$ and $A$ into $A_x$, $A_y$ and $A_z$. Then, to find the value of $A$,  $A_x$,  $A_y$ and $A_z$ are each calculated as:
$$A_x=A_y=A_z=({{\frac {m}{2\pi kT}}})^{1/2}$$ Thus the value of $A$ is found to be:
$$A=A_xA_yA_z=({\frac {m}{2\pi kT}})^{3/2}$$
My question is this: can A be not directly calculated from the equation $f(v)=Ae^{-{\epsilon}/{kT}}$, like $A_x$, $A_y$ and $A_z$ were?
I can't seem to find an answer to this online. But if what I just mentioned is in fact possible, please also mention the limits over which the term $e^{-{\frac {1}{2}m{v}^2}/{kT}}$ has to be integrated.

Comment: I've found that 'a normalizing constant is a constant by which an everywhere non-negative function must be multiplied so the area under its graph is 1.' This is what you mean when you say normalization constant right? Also, how do I find the normalization constant in the case of $f(v)$, if this is what you mean?

Comment: Thank you @Poutnik. But I don't think I can understand (I'm in 10th grade). So, could you please explain your latest comment a bit more? I understood what you said, until getting the symbolic value of the integral. But I couldn't understand much after that.

Comment: Doing it three dimensions the integral would instead be a triple integral dxdydz that you'd split up into three independent integrals identical to the one you solved for the 1D case, so it's the same math

Comment: After formulation of the answer, now redundant comments have been deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be calculated directly, but the probability of a given speed must be integrated over the whole space of velocity vector components.

We integrate the [Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_distribution) values

$$\exp{(-\frac {E}{kT})}=\exp{(-\frac {mv^2}{2kT})}$$

in the integral over the 3D space of velocity components $v_\mathrm{x}$, $v_\mathrm{y}$, $v_\mathrm{y}$, using the radial spherical coordinate $v \equiv r$, where $v=\sqrt{v_\mathrm{x}^2+v_\mathrm{y}^2+
v_\mathrm{z}^2}$:

$$C\int_0^{\infty}{4\pi v^2\exp{(\frac{-mv^2}{2kT})}\mathrm{d}v}=1$$

as for spherical coordinates, $\mathrm{d}V=4\pi r^2 \mathrm{d}r$

The value of the above finite integral:

$$\left(\dfrac{2\pi kT}{m}\right)^{3/2}$$

is the reciprocal value of the normalisation constant:

$$C=\left(\dfrac{m}{2\pi kT}\right)^{\frac 32}$$

which sets the probability that a molecule has some speed to certainty, as  $\int_0^{\infty}{p(v)\mathrm{d}v}=1$

We have now finally the complete normalized probability density function $p(v)$ for the speed $v$, known as the [Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93Boltzmann_distribution):

$$p(v)=\left(\dfrac{m}{2\pi kT}\right)^{\frac 32}4\pi v^2\exp{(-\frac{mv^2}{2kT})}$$

---

The finite integral value can be conveniently obtained by putting the integrated function `4*pi*v^2*exp((-mv^2)/(2kT))` to the [online symbolic integrator](https://www.integral-calculator.com/) with limits 0 and $+\infty$.