# According to Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, what is probability distribution function proportional to?

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetic-theory-of-gases, statistical-mechanics

If, according to the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution

$${f(v)}\propto\exp\left(-\frac{\varepsilon}{kT}\right),\tag{1}$$

which is the equation from which the whole final equation is derived, then why is the final equation

$$f(v) = 4\pi v^2\left(\frac{m}{2{\pi}kT}\right)^{3/2}\exp\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2kT}\right)?\tag{2}$$

Clearly, here

$${f(v)}\propto v^2\exp\left(-\frac{mv^2}{2kT}\right).\tag{3}$$

Where have I made a mistake in understanding this?

Comment: The link you shared goes to a not-so-informative website. What's $\epsilon$? Let's say that $\epsilon = mv^2$. The proportionality statement still holds.

Comment: The 'additional' terms are obtained when transforming the probability distribution from 3-D distribution into magnitude of the velocity vector (averaged over direction) using spherical coordinates. Referenced from https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/5-62-physical-chemistry-ii-spring-2008/resources/28_562ln08/

Comment: [Closely related, nearly  duplicate](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/164064/why-is-the-value-of-a-in-the-expression-for-boltzmanns-distribution-of-speed) // You may confuse Boltzmann and Maxwell-Boltzmann distributions, with the latter based on the former, adding the v^2 factor from dV=4pi.r^2 dr, being integrated for the radius spherical coordinate.

Comment: The funny thing is both posts share the same OP.

Comment: @Poutnik I *thought* it was familiar...

Comment: @ToddMinehardt yes, the link is not the actual source that the expression was taken from. As mentioned in my comment on orthocresol's answer, it was taken from Peter Atkins' Physical Chemistry. Also Poutnik, sorry for the bother, but could you please go more into what the difference between the Boltzmann and the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution is? Is it that, as orthocresol mentioned in his answer, the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution is a 'vector form' of the Boltzmann one?

Comment: @theawesomenerd I have thought you got it in the linked Q/A. The BD is very general distribution, about probability of a state with given energy. The MBD  is specific BD application on translational kinetic energy. As all velocity vectors with given speed share this energy and the probability is therefore further weighted by the 4piv^2 factor, what is surface of the sphere in velocity vector space.

Comment: Oh I understood now @Poutnik. Sorry for the bother, again. So the BD is like the quadratic formula while the MBD is analogous to a formula for deriving the square root of a given number, right?

Comment: Not sure if this analogy fits. MBD is like "how many ways can the molecule have the given E_kin (proportional to  4.pi.v^2)"  times "what is probability it could have such E_kin (proportional to exp(-E_kin/(kT))"

Comment: @Poutnik I like to think of it as the "degeneracy factor" $g$ in the Boltzmann formula $p \propto g\exp(-E/kT)$, although I'm not sure whether that's 100% technically correct.

Comment: @orthocresol  Yes, I have also thought to use the term degeneration. I think it is correct but I was not sure if it would clarify or confuse things for the OP.

Comment: @Poutnik I did not literally go for the same relation as between BD and MBD. I meant in my analogy that the latter can be derived from the former. Either way, all the things are clear now.

Comment: You could see how MBD could be derived from BD in your prior Q/A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The $v$ in your first expression (that $f(v) \propto \exp(-\varepsilon/kT)$) most likely refers to the true velocity which is a *vector*

$$\vec{v} = (v_x, v_y, v_z),$$

whereas the $v$ in the Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution refers to the *magnitude* of the velocity

$$v = |\vec{v}| = \sqrt{v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2}.$$

The latter is more useful to a chemist because we don't really care which direction the particle is moving in, only its speed. However, note that there are *many possible combinations* of $(v_x, v_y, v_z)$ which yield the same magnitude $v$; so the formula needs to be adjusted for this. The factor ends up being $4\pi v^2$, which is the surface area of a sphere with radius $v$ (you can think of the surface of this sphere as representing all possible velocities with magnitude $v$).

My suggestion would be to look for a derivation in a good physical chemistry textbook, which should explain this more thoroughly.

Comment: Actually, I did read the first expression that I gave, in Physical Chemistry by Peter Atkins, but I really couldn't share the link because I have a hard copy, and I couldn't find any similar derivation on the internet. So, I had to  link that website. But the book did in fact give $f(v)\propto e^{\frac{-\epsilon}{kT}}$

Comment: Also, I found that the derivation in the same mentioned book is wrong in many places such as equating $f(v)$ with $f(v_x).f(v_y).f(v_z)$.

Comment: I think I understand now. We were taking $\vec{v}$ and therefore only one combination of $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_z$ is present(due to only one direction). Thus we need not add the $4πv^2$ part to accommodate for the total volume in the velocity space. Is this what you meant @orthocresol?

Comment: I think that's pretty much what I said, yeah.